# Apex Trigger to update custom object

Tags: apex, trigger

I am currently working to create a trigger to create a record of Account IDs, Opportunity IDs, and Parent Account IDs in a custom object based on a new opportunity being created.

I am looking to update the custom object with the Account ID, Opportunity ID, Parent Account ID when a standard opportunity record is created.

The data will push from the opportunity object to the custom object and create a new custom object record containing the opportunity's ID information.

Any thoughts?

```
trigger OpptyHierarchy on Opportunity_Hierarchy__c (before insert, beofre update) {

        Set<string> OpportunityID = new Set<String>();
    for  (Opportunity_Hierarchy__c tc : trigger.new) {
        if (tc.Account_Name__c != NULL) {OpportunityID.add(tc.Account_Name__c);
        }
    }

    Map<String, Opportunity> Opportunity = new Map <String, Opportunity>();
    for (Opportunity obj : [SELECT ID, AccountID, Main_Account__c, Enterprise_Account__c
                from Opportunity
                Where OpportunityID IN AccountID]) {Opportunity.put(obj.Account_Name__c, Obj);
    }

    for (Opportunity_Hierarchy__c t: trigger.new) {
        if (Opportunity.containsKey(tc.Account_Name__c)) tc.Account_Name_Lookup__c = Opportunity.get(tc.Account_Name__c_.ID;
        tc.Main_Account__c = Opportunity.get(tc.Account_Name__c).Main_Account__c;
        tc.Enterprise_Account__c = Opportunity.get(tc.Account_Name__c).Enterprise_Account__c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds nice. Let me know when you have some code written.

Comment: Use `Process Builder`...

Comment: Providing the code that you've developed up to this point is generally helpful. In this situation though, I think that we should probably start with going into more detail about why you decided to create a new object just to hold relationship fields. What exactly are you hoping to accomplish in the end? You can fairly easily query all of this information from an `Opportunity`, why isn't that an option?

Comment: We are using an app that can provide reporting combining our custom account hierarchy (not using the OOTB hierarchy).  The app is limited to pulling only 2 levels worth of detail (Parent to Child) in one view and their designated opportunities to be viewed on the parent account and not via a report.

Comment: I added an example.  Since I am not able to pull in the IDs on the __c fields for the accounts, I pulled in the __c name.

Comment: @AwesomeUser2 - What do you mean you cannot pull the Ids? If the `__c` field is a lookup it is the ID of the record

Comment: apologies @Eric I can.

Comment: Any feedback on the code above?